# Do feature requests on per-site metas get looked at?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

Do feature requests on per-site metas get looked at?  Should we cross post our feature-requests here for visibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site moderators are supposed to escalate feature requests that get a lot of traction on the local per-site metas.

I would not open a feature-req here that doesn't have reasonable support on your local meta site, first.